# vb.net Textbox Control

Tags: vb.net

I have text in a textbox. The content is "10/BSC/01".

"10" = current year

"BSC" = department

"01" = the roll number  of student

If I press a command button the "01" should be incremented without affecting the other fields.

What should I do ?

Comment: It is all going to String Manipulation :) Read these web pages http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets7p1.html / http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson13.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudocode:

dim arry = textbox.text.split("/")
dim num = ctype(arry(2),int)
num +=1
numstr = num.tostring(prefix with 0)
textbox.text = arry(0) + "/" + arry(1) + "/" + numstr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28VS.71%29.aspx) to extract your elements.

```
Dim input As String = "10/BSC/01"
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, "(\d+)/(\w+)/(\d+)")

Dim year As Integer = Integer.Parse(matches(0).Groups(1).Value)
Dim course As String = matches(0).Groups(2).Value
Dim rollNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(matches(0).Groups(3).Value)

Dim result As String = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", year + 1, course, rollNumber)
```